# AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase

I am trying to connect to couchbase which is installed on linux server using Spring data 2.2.8 release. Our Couchbase
db is Enterprise Edition 5.0.0 build 2873.

There is cluster user id and password which i am not able to pass from AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration method and getting 401 error (Unknown ResponseStatus with Protocol HTTP: 401).

But when i tried with java sdk with below code i am able to connect successfully.

```
Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(“servername”);
cluster.authenticate(“userid”, “password”);
Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket(“bucket”);
```

Could you please help me to understand what i am doing wrong with Spring data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a user with the same name as the bucket and set the password there, as [I also answered in this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46995003/couchbase-5-bucket-password-setting).

As mentioned there, the docs should cover this and if there's anything confusing there, please click the "feedback" button and offer what could be improved!

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/security/security-authorization.html https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/security/concepts-rba-for-apps.html https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/security/security-resources-under-access-control.html

Comment: Thank you Matt for clarification.. :) i have the connection now.