# Spring Boot : Couchbase 5.0.1 - Could not connect to couchbaseDB

Tags: spring, spring-boot, couchbase

I'm new to couchbaseDB and I encountering an issue connecting my spring boot application to database when I upgraded my couchbaseDB to 5.0.1.

Here is my configuration:

***CouchbaseConfig.java***

```
@Configuration
public class CouchbaseConfig {

   @Value("${spring.couchbase.bootstrap-hosts:localhost}")
   private String couchbaseUri;

   @Value("${spring.data.couchbase.bucket.name}")
   private String bucketName;

   public Cluster cluster() {
      return CouchbaseCluster.create(couchbaseUri).authenticate("user","password");
   }

   public Bucket bucket() {
      return cluster().openBucket(bucketName);
   }
```

I'm able to open the bucket I created but it will close immediately because of the exception and it always ask the "default" bucket's password which is not existing on the database. Here is the error log:

***Error Log:***

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'couchbaseClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/couchbase/CouchbaseAutoConfiguration$CouchbaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket]: Factory method 'couchbaseClient' threw exception; nested exception is com.couchbase.client.java.error.InvalidPasswordException: Passwords for bucket "default" do not match.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sample.project.api.ProjectApiApplication.main(ProjectApiApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket]: Factory method 'couchbaseClient' threw exception; nested exception is com.couchbase.client.java.error.InvalidPasswordException: Passwords for bucket "default" do not match.**
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.couchbase.client.java.error.InvalidPasswordException: Passwords for bucket "default" do not match.
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncCluster$OpenBucketErrorHandler.call(CouchbaseAsyncCluster.java:644) ~[java-client-2.5.3.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncCluster$OpenBucketErrorHandler.call(CouchbaseAsyncCluster.java:627) ~[java-client-2.5.3.jar:na]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:140) ~[rxjava-1.3.3.jar:1.3.3]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeMap.java:88) ~[rxjava-1.3.3.jar:1.3.3]
    at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onError(Subscribers.java:230) ~[rxjava-1.3.3.jar:1.3.3]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:273) ~[rxjava-1.3.3.jar:1.3.3]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:216) ~[rxjava-1.3.3.jar:1.3.3]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) ~[rxjava-1.3.3.jar:1.3.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

My question is how not to open"default" bucket and open only the bucket I created in the couchbaseDB? I hope you could help me regarding this matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couchbase 5 bucket password setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46995003/couchbase-5-bucket-password-setting)

Answer (score 0):

This should not be happening unless I'm not seeing important parts of your code. Which couchbase sdk version are you using?

Here is a working example:

```
CouchbaseCluster server = CouchbaseCluster.create("testServer");
server.authenticate("user","password");
Bucket testBucket = server.openBucket("testBucket");
```

The above will only 'successfully' open `testBucket` if the user that authenticated (user) have access to it, else it will throw an `InvalidPasswordException`. You'll not be hitting any buckets in the above code but `testBucket`.

Comment: My configuration is the same as yours, I declared a bucket named "user" and the application can open it but still the application is hitting the "default" bucket. Maybe I try to update my libraries. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @MichaelAngeloDelaCruz Ya could be, you didn't tell me which version are you using. Try to update to the latest version.